# How does this user have two Stack Overflow accounts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, accounts

[This user](https://stackexchange.com/users/2409365/mertyildiran?tab=accounts) has two accounts listed for Stack Overflow. One has a bunch of questions and answers on it, and the other seems to be a ghost account with zero activity and a blank profile page but with nearly the same reputation.

Here's the ["real" account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104879/mertyildiran): [image: Real account]

And here's the ["ghost" account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7995639/mertyildiran): [image: Ghost account]

This appears to be a bug. I can also reproduce it on the SE iOS app.

Comment: The fact that two Stack Overflow accounts are showing under "Communities" confirms that this is not intended behavior. It's definitely a bug.

Comment: Related: [Network profile list same account twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257515)

Comment: SE employees can merge accounts. Probably that man had two separate SE accounts with one SO account in each, and those got merged. They still have 2 separate identifiers for backward compatibility, while being essentially the same account. I think the only problem is that it's shown in the interface twice.

Comment: If SO allows multiple accounts anyway, what's wrong with a "conscious" collection of your multiple accounts at one place? In either case, SO would know if 2 accounts belong to the same user(for same IP at least)

Comment: @pulp_fiction Creating two SO accounts shouldn't be too much of a problem, as long as they don't interact (upvote one another's posts etc.) What would you be planning to do with such a collection?

Comment: @MrLister : I think you got the wrong idea. I meant, if you are allowed to have 2 different SO account officially(with or without SO knowing about it) then if I were to create an account while "joining" with the current set of SE accounts that I have, it should hardly be a surprise. If anything, I am being honest. Regarding the cross upvoting, people do engage in those practices(as I have read on other meta posts) and mods and the community take action whenever they come to know. But, the point is, this(OP's post) doesn't qualify as a Bug.

Comment: @pulp_fiction Yes it does. Just look at the "ghost" account: it's new, 5 days old and the user already has 2900 rep without asking or answering any questions! Also, his "top network post" questions go to posts by the real account.

Comment: @MrLister The "top network post" questions are all from his other accounts on the other communities. Notice how the account ID number in the URL changes when you visit your profile on a different SE site. So that part isn't a bug. The bug here is the fact that the Stack Overflow accounts aren't merged properly (according to the related post).

Comment: @4castle : Then what does 2 different rep figures mean for his SO accounts? Is one 2.9K and other the difference of 2nd and first Ac?

Comment: @4castle Sorry, yeah, but the "View more network posts" at the bottom goes to the same page as the one in the real account.

Comment: Something's definitely off here and not in a way that I expected. Most times when we see multiple same-site profiles listed under the same account, it's due to an error during a profile merge. There's no merge record in this case. I'm digging further.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So, the short version of the issue here is that I'm an idiot.

The long version:

While most of our database queries are written in SQL directly (and executed via [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)), there are some models that still use LINQ to SQL. User objects are one of those models. I pushed some code at the end of the week before last (right before going on vacation, natch) that affected recording of some UserHistory events. Instead of loading up an L2S-aware `User`, I just did a plain SQL query, so the user history L2S code helpfully inserted what it thought were new User records.

The code is now fixed, and I cleaned up the affected profiles. Thanks for the report!